# Can't link GLFW3 in Linux

Tags: c, linux, glfw, vulkan, linker-errors

i am decide to learn Vulkan. The only utility library supports Vulkan is GLFW3. So i decide to use GLFW3.

I'm install the libglfw3 and libglfw3-dev on the terminal. Of course before that i am install the Mesa Vulkan drivers and development files.

I write this small application:

```
int main(int ACount, char *Arguments[])
{   
    if(!glfwInit())
    {
        printf("Error! Can't initialize the GLFW3 \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(!glfwVulkanSupported())
    {
        printf("Error! Vulkan is not supported by your system \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

And the promblem is:

When i try to compile the application with -lvulkan and -lglfw on GCC, compiler gives this error:

```
Vulkan.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `glfwVulkanSupported'
```

And after that i tried to compile with -lglfw3, but compiler gived an error again:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw3
```

How i can solve that?

Comment: "*gived an error again*" Is it the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, i solve the problem. GLFW 3 is not supports glfwVulkanSupported, but GLFW 3.2, which is unstable, supports. Because of it is not stable, when i install libglfw3, i am installed GLFW 3.1 not 3.2.

Comment: Where did you read that it's unstable version? 3.2.1 seems to be the latest version (with additional fixes!)